# Generate headline for each month, sorted by month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, for-loop

I use for() to generate headlines for each months and select corresponding data from a database like this:

```
$year = '2013';

for ($i = 12; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $sql = "SELECT stuff 
    FROM table 
    WHERE year(date) = '".$year."'
    and month(date) = '".$i."'
    ORDER BY date ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Unable to select data.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num > 0) { 
        echo '<h3>'.date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, $year)).'</h3>';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, the monthly grouped datasets are sorted DESC (December 2013, November 2013, October 2013, etc). I would like to sort them the other way around: January 2013, February 2013, March 2013, etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the for loop as follows?

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++)
```

Isn't what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this without a loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT stuff, month(date) AS month
FROM table 
WHERE YEAR(date) = '".$year."'
ORDER BY date ASC";
```

And then loop all your results and compare field "month" to process every month as you wish...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    switch($row["month"]) {
        case "1":
              //Process January...
             break;
        case "2":
              //Process Fenriary...
             break;
        //And so on...
    }
}
```

This is ALOT! more performant because multiple queries (especially queries in a loop) are never good for your MySQL server. It can slow down loading time of your website drastically and eats alot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the loop?

```
$sql = "SELECT stuff 
FROM  table 
ON year(date) = '".$year."'
ORDER BY date ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Unable to select data.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) 
{ 
    echo '<h3>'.date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, $year)).'</h3>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Or if you want to force a row back even when there is nothing for that month:-

```
$year = '2013';

$sql = "SELECT stuff 
FROM (SELECT 1 i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) poss_months
LEFT OUTER JOIN table 
ON year(date) = '".$year."'
and month(date) = poss_months.i
ORDER BY date ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Unable to select data.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) 
{ 
    echo '<h3>'.date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, $year)).'</h3>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```